# Printing individual variable of a structure in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, struct, gdb

I'm debugging the Linux kernel. I can print the content of a structure like this:

```
(gdb) p *(struct rb_node*)0xffff88813b160388
 $6 = {
 __rb_parent_color = 1, 
 rb_right = 0xffff88813b31a5c8, 
 rb_left = 0xffff88813b1608c8
}
```

Instead of printing the whole structure content, I'm trying to print a particular value of a structure. For example, something like, 
 `rb_right = 0xffff88813b31a5c8`.
I try the following way, it shows me an error, I'm not quite sure if this is the right approach or not.

```
(gdb) p *((struct rb_node*)rb_right) 0xffff88813b160388
 No symbol "rb_right" in current context.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a structure, use C syntax:

```
p (*(struct rb_node*) 0xffff88813b160388).rb_right
```